# Twig: Render block multiple times: parsed, escaped, verbatim

Tags: twig, block, verbatim

I’m building a pattern library that displays my production twig partials with some additional information. Under each pattern, I want to have two code snippets that I want to be generated from my pattern. One is the parsed HTML, the other one is my Twig code directly from the partial file, including variables and other Twig code.

### Question

**How do I reuse a block that I already parsed and rendered on my page, but in its unparsed form?**

### Files:

- `moduleXYZ.html` (production module code), which extends…
- `_pattern.html` (wrapper with additional informational code for pattern library), which uses…
- `_pattern_foot.html` (in here, the block defined in `_pattern.html` and overwritten in `moduleXYZ.html` should be displayed verbatim)

### moduleXYZ.html:

```
{% extends '_pattern.html' %}
{% block pattern %}
  <h2>{{ variable|default('Some placeholder text') }}</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

### _pattern.html:

```
{% block pattern %}
  No pattern defined.
{% endblock %}
{% use '_pattern-foot.html' %}
{% block('patternfoot') %}
```

### _pattern-foot.html:

```
{% block patternfoot %}
  <h2>HTML for this pattern:</h2>
  <pre><code>
  {{ block('pattern')|e }} {# THIS WORKS, escaped HTML is displayed. #}
  </code></pre>

  <h2>Twig for this pattern:</h2>
  <pre><code>
  {{ block('pattern')|e }} {# THIS IS NOT WORKING, of course, because the block is already parsed. #}
  </code></pre>

{% endblock %}
```

### What didn’t work

I managed to get the result I want by wrapping the "pattern" block in `moduleXYZ.html` in `{% verbatim %}`, but then of course my logic/variables go unparsed in the module itself, too.

I understand it’s not possible to pass variables into the `block()` function, so I also can’t toggle verbatim conditionally for my reused block (or can I?).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?